# For loop, repetitive calculation in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, repeat

```
from random import uniform

prob = [0.25,0.30,0.45]

def onetrial(prob):
    u=uniform(0,1)
    if 0 < u <= prob[0]:
        return 11
    if prob[0] < u <= prob[0]+prob[1]:
        return 23
    if prob[0]+prob[1] < u <= prob[0]+prob[1]+prob[2]:
        return 39

print onetrial(prob)
```

I wonder how to reduce the repetitive part in the def using some for-loop techniques. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like some type of roulette wheel selection .. I don't think the code is that unclear, will `prob` become larger or vary? I'm just curious about the motivation for this - thanks

Comment: you don't need to test the `<` part (handled by the previous if).

Comment: You can skip the last `if` entirely if you assume the probabilities sum to 1.0. That will be safer too in the event that rounding causes you to miss the last condition and run off the end of the function.

Comment: Though it gets messy and may not be what you asked for it could be done as a crazy oneliner (that can be split up to understandable bits) given that you have `u`: `[11,23,39][map(lambda x: u<=x, [sum(prob[0:i+1]) for i in xrange(len(prob))]).index(True)]`

Comment: Thanks all. @Levon, the code is to generate a random variable X with the probability mass function (prob).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you call `onetrial` frequently, calculate the [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) first to make it a bit faster:

```
from random import uniform

vals = [11, 23, 39]
prob = [0.25, 0.30, 0.45]
cdf = [sum(prob[0:i+1]) for i in xrange(3)]

def onetrial(vals, cdf):
    u = uniform(0, 1)
    for i in range(3):
        if u <= cdf[i]:
            return vals[i]
```

You could use [bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) to make it even faster.

Comment: why do you have prob in the function?

Comment: This line `def onetrial(prob):` should be `def onetrial(cdf, vals):` I think

Answer (score 1):

The following is equivalent to your current code and it uses a for loop:

```
from random import uniform

prob = [0.25, 0.30, 0.45]

def onetrial(prob):
    u = uniform(0, 1)
    return_values = [11, 23, 39]
    total_prob = 0
    for i in range(3):
        total_prob += prob[i]
        if u <= total_prob:
            return return_values[i]
```

I am a little unclear on the relationship between the values you return and the probabilities, it seems like for your code `prob` will always have exactly 3 elements, so I made that assumption as well.

Answer (score 1):

I like F.J's answer, but I would use a list of tuples, assuming you can easily do so:

```
from random import uniform

prob = [(0.25, 11), (0.30, 23), (0.45, 39)]

def onetrial(prob):
    u = uniform(0, 1)
    total_prob = 0
    for i in range(3):
        total_prob += prob[i][0]
        if u <= total_prob:
            return prob[i][1]
```